# Admins only command

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

Only selected user id's should have permission to use this command. like below only user ids added in this list should get permission to use that command.

```
def is_any_user(ids):
    async def predicate(ctx):
        return ctx.author.id in ids
    return commands.check(predicate)

LIST_OF_ADMINS = [3557657657647676, 36567565756766767, 343657687786435432]

@bot.command(pass_context=True)
@is_any_user(LIST_OF_ADMINS)
async def hello(ctx):
     await bot.say("Hello {}".format(ctx.message.author.mention))
```

Comment: Try something like `if ctx.(some_id) in LIST_OF_ADMINS`? Or create a new role for those people

Comment: @cricket_007 my bot is installed in many server so role can be created by them. so i need to restrict some commands by some used ids list.

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own check that can decorate the command

```
def is_any_user(ids):
    def predicate(ctx):
        return ctx.message.author.id in ids
    return commands.check(predicate)

LIST_OF_ADMINS = ['3557657657647676', '36567565756766767', '343657687786435432']

@bot.command(pass_context=True)
@is_any_user(LIST_OF_ADMINS)
async def hello(ctx):
     await bot.say("Hello {}".format(ctx.message.author.mention))
```

You can read more about checks in the `commands` extension [in the documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html#checks)

Comment: @Bosen Oops, I forgot to add `commands.check`.  It should be fixed now.

Comment: @Bosen Looks like in the async branch doesn't want the predicate to be a coroutine.

Comment: now its not replying to anyone getting error while using command.    `return all(predicate(context) for predicate in predicates)
  File "E:\sample.py", line 17, in predicate
    return ctx.author.id in ids
AttributeError: 'Context' object has no attribute 'author'`

Comment: @Bosen Yeah, `message`s have authors, not contexts.  Your lsit of admins should also be a list of strings, not ints.