# How do you make a Discord bot respond to commands in DMs? (Python)

Tags: python, command, discord, discord.py, dm

I've just started writing Discord bots. I'm currently working on a bot that helps with Dungeons & Dragons games (dice rolling and initiative tracking are working at the moment). I've gotten my bot to send private rolls to a DM with the user that called the command within the server, but within the actual DM, the bot only responds to the `help` command.

I've read through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60753333/discord-py-how-do-i-get-my-bot-to-read-dms-that-are-sent-to-it-and-either-pri?newreg=21cde2d7e7284f18be70375fff78f7ea) explanation, but it still doesn't seem useful to me, since I want it to respond to commands in DMs rather than grab the content of the messages sent to it in DMs. For example, let's say I'm in a server with the bot, and I use the `whisperRoll` command, which causes the bot to send me a DM with my dice roll result. Now that I have a private chat with the bot, I'd like to make another roll just for myself so that other players can't see it, so I try to use the `roll` command in the DM channel. What I'd like it to do is respond to the command in the DM in the same way it would respond in a server.

I'm wondering if there's possibly a set of default commands that are registered as "valid" for the bot to respond to in DMs that I'm missing? I can't really find an answer to this anywhere, and I don't even know where to start.

Thanks so much for the help!

EDIT: My current code, which is giving me a `CommandInvokeError`:

```py
def _prefix_callable(bot, msg):
    prefix = '!'
    guild = msg.guild
    if p.prefixInfo == []:
        pass
    else:
        prefix = p.getPrefix(guild)
    
    if not guild:
        return commands.when_mentioned_or(prefix)(bot, msg)
    return commands.when_mentioned_or(prefix)(bot, msg)

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=_prefix_callable, description=description, help_command = None)
```

p.getPrefix(guild) calls this code:

```py
def getPrefix(self, guild):
        for data in self.prefixInfo:
            if data[0] == str(hash(guild)):
                return data[1]
        return "!"
```

I'm currently having it search through a csv to find the right prefix for the given guild.

Comment: Your current code isn't trying to perform any actions in a DM channel as far as I can see. Did you add the actual part that's causing you the error? The traceback should be showing you what line it is coming from.

Comment: @stijndcl Within the normal command `roll`, which I'm testing in the DM channel, I have `await ctx.message.delete()`. It's that line that's giving me an error. Am I not allowed to delete messages in a DM channel?

Comment: The code for `roll` is NOT In your post, you should add the parts that cause the error so we can help you fix it... And yes, you *can't* delete messages in DM.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `discord.channel.DMChannel` object

For example:

```
async def check(ctx, arg):
    if isinstance(ctx.channel, discord.channel.DMChannel):
        await ctx.send(arg)
```

Answer (score 0):

For usage in dms with prefix

```py
def get_prefix(message):
    prefix = "?"  # default prefix
    if not message.guild:  # if in dms
        return commands.when_mentioned_or(prefix)(bot, message)
    #you can set a guild/server specific one here
    return commands.when_mentioned_or(prefix)(bot, message)


bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=get_prefix, case_insensitive=True) #bot allows you to make commands
```

Then for the command, you would need to do:

```py
@bot.command()
async def whisperroll(ctx):
    await ctx.author.send("some random thing")
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! I tried this, but I'm still having issues. It's giving me the following error: `CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: Forbidden: 403 Forbidden (error code: 50003): Cannot execute action on a DM channel`.

Comment: @DanaHarris without seeing your code there's no way we can know what's causing that...

Comment: I'll add my current code up in the main post, so you can see it. But I added your lines of code to my already existing `_prefix_callable` function, which I was passing to the bot.

Comment: @DanaHarris your bot cannot dm the person as it's not allowed