# Only allow two people to use a discord bot command

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I've been working on a discord bot recently and have run into an issue where I would like to have only me and one other user be able to use a command, but I just can't figure out how, I read up on exceptions and lists but I just can't seem to wrap my head around how to use them, I'm basically learning as I go along, some stuff comes easier than others.

I know I am going to have to add and remove stuff I just don't know what, where and how.

Well, if I'm being honest, I tried being a nutcase and ended up copying the first return and pasting it below itself. I knew that probably wouldn't work. I also tried to add a comma after the first id with a space then put the second id.

```py
def is_me():
    def predicate(ctx):
        return ctx.message.author.id == 413956481197670401
    return commands.check(predicate)

@client.command()
@is_me()
async def Secret(ctx):
    await ctx.send(f'{ctx.author.mention} Only you!')

@Secret.error
async def Secret_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.CheckFailure):
        await ctx.send('Nothing here buckaroo.')
```

Well, my end goal is to have it so whenever one of us trigger the command, it spits out what I have it set to, and when anyone else uses it, it spits out the error.

However, whenever I tried it out with the comma attempt, it just allowed anyone to use the command. There were no error messages.

I am sorry for this text wall.

Comment: Are you asking how to express `ctx.author.id in (id1, id2)`?  (Note the parentheses around the ids)

Comment: @PatrickHaugh Well, yes, that would most likely be what I am looking for, but I have taught myself how to do this, and I can't seem to wrap my head around it.

Comment: I think [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50667963/admins-only-command/50668067#50668067) covers what you're trying to do.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh Yes it did, I just had to update some of it to match current discord.py. Much thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so you gotta define the command first off. Once you make that command, inside THAT, have an IF statement to check if the ID is equal to whoever `or` whoever else (use their IDs), if it's not, return null, or more user friendly return a message with no permissions.

Or you could make a variable storing both IDs, maybe as an array? Then instead of using the IDs, just use the array and its indexes.

Answer (score 0):

```
def is_Mod(user_id): 
    ## This function will check if the given id is already in the file. True if in file, False if not ##
        with open('Mod.txt', 'r') as f:
            if str(user_id) in f.read():
                return True
            else:
                return False
```

Defined now we'll use it as

```
@client.command()
async def Secret(ctx):
    if is_Mod(ctx.author.id) == True:
        await ctx.send("Your response")
    else:
       #error
```

Answer (score 0):

Discord.py provides `@is_owner` decorator so only owners can use a specific commands. You can provide owner_ids explicitly in a list on initialization or you can store the ids in db with command name as dict or something and write your own decorator function comparing the author id with the ids present in db, return true if the id is in list else false

Answer (score 0):

allowing 2 or more people to use a command can be done in alot of ways, down below is the method i use for allowing certain people/IDs to use commands:

```
IDCARD = [ID1, ID2] <---Make a list of IDs

@client.command()
async def hello(ctx):
if ctx.author.id in IDCARD:
    #your code here (Hello World)
else:
    await ctx.send('Access Denied!')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be your own decorator, you have to do it like this:

```
def is_me(func):
    @functools.wraps(func) # Don't forget to import functools
    async def wrapper(ctx, *param, **kwargs):
        if ctx.message.author.id == 413956481197670401:
            await func(ctx, *param, **kwargs)
        else:
            await ctx.send("Nothing here buckaroo.")
    return wrapper

@client.command()
@is_me
async def Secret(ctx):
    await ctx.send(f'{ctx.author.mention} Only you!')
```

But you should also know that you can use decorators provided by discord.py to do the checking you want to do. For example :

- https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html#checks
- https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot.before_invoke